# Django: Using a Relational and Nosql database in same project

Tags: django

Can we use relational and nosql database in same django project.

As django package for relational and no-sql(django-nonrel) are different. Is there a way we can use both kind of databases in same project ?

Comment: You can consider memcached as no-sql, which is used extensively in Django. Also there are nosql capabilities in postgres and there are other nifty solutions such as django-redit. Al of them in parallel with default ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although it depends on the backend for the NoSQL database. Django-nonrel is not necessarily required for a NoSQL database backend. From my experience, it is possible to use SQLite and Cassandra in the same project. We don't use django-nonrel because the Cassandra backend for Django works fine on vanilla Django.